# Ordering list of tuples by ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, tuples

I want to show IDs and tags and sort them by top tags by ascending order.

```
word_counts = word_tuple.reduceByKey(lambda total, count: total + count)
word_counts.take(30)

[('id,tags', 1),
 ('"16586898","', 1),
 ('javascript', 3276),
 ('data-structures', 48),
 ('documentation', 1153),
 ('data-visualization', 10),
 ('"', 27109),
 ('"1828522","', 1),
 ('api', 634),
 ('console', 19),
 ('installation', 17),
 ('glassfish', 5),
 ('admin', 3),
 ('"25883048","', 1),
 ('regex', 500),
 ('bash', 375),
 ('sed', 56),
 ('"1879493","', 1),
```

Comment: Can you explain the first two lines?  They are not native Python.

Comment: did one of the below answers help? if so, feel free to accept one, or ask questions to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `sorted` with `key` parameter:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])

# [('id,tags', 1),
#  ('"16586898","', 1),
#  ('"1828522","', 1),
#  ('"25883048","', 1),
#  ('"1879493","', 1),
#  ('admin', 3),
#  ('glassfish', 5),
#  ('data-visualization', 10),
#  ('installation', 17),
#  ('console', 19),
#  ('data-structures', 48),
#  ('sed', 56),
#  ('bash', 375),
#  ('regex', 500),
#  ('api', 634),
#  ('documentation', 1153),
#  ('javascript', 3276),
#  ('"', 27109)]
```